# Как добавить и использовать локализацию (мультиязычность) для определенного поля в моделе?

Tags: python, django

Как сделать мультиязычность в поле:

```
content = PlaceholderField(
    "base_content", 
    verbose_name=_("content"), 
    help_text="Additional content"
)
```

Полная модель:

```
class Catalog(TranslatableModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="categories", null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('slug'), unique=True, help_text=_("For use into URL"))
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), null=True, blank=True)
    main_img = AnyImageField(_('Image'), blank=True, null=True)
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        content = PlaceholderField("base_content", verbose_name=_("content"), help_text="Additional content"),
        contentitem_set = ContentItemRelation(),
        placeholder_set = PlaceholderRelation(),
    )
```

Нужно сделать мультиязычность для поля контент.

Comment: Читайте про [localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/)